# Read a text file and import it into a filter sortof

Tags: java, replace

I want to take a file that says:

```
wordone
somthing16
wordsof
varyinglengths
```

What I want to do is have

```
message.replace(textabove, "***")
```

And have it loop so that it covers anything in the text file. I currently have

```
message = message.replaceall("wordone", "foxin");
message = message.replaceall("somthing16", "derp");
```

etc. over and over again. and trying to make it easier on me.

Comment: I think this question needs clarification. How does the software know `wordone` matches `foxin`?

Comment: Also, replaceAll is for regular expressions. For fixed strings, use replace.